# populate image array with parse in swift

Tags: xcode, image, swift, parse-platform

Hi I'm new with swift and parse.com, I'm trying do populate my array with already saved images in parse, try to use the dispatch_async but don't know how this works, heres the code:

```
//imageArray declaration in table:
var imageArray: Array<UIImage> = []


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    var query = PFQuery(className: "ParseClass")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { ( objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if(error == nil) {

            let imageObjects = objects as! [PFObject]

            for object in objects! {

                let thumbNail = object["columnInParse"] as! PFFile

                thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if (error == nil) {

                        if let image = UIImage(data:imageData!) {

 //here where the error appears: Cannot invoke 'dispatch_async' with an argument list of type '(dispatch_queue_t!, () -> _)' 
                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {                                     
                                cell.image.image = self.imageArray.append( image )
                            }

                        }

                    }
                })
            }
        }
        else{

            println("Error in retrieving \(error)")

        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Hope you people understand that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to use that dispatch block is like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                //perform your work here
                self.imageArray.append(image)
                cell.image.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
            })
```

Another reason that the compiler is giving this warning is because you're trying to append images to an array *and* set that as the cells image. What you should be doing is shown above.

Finally, I would recommend moving your queries out of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and into seperate methods as this is bad code design.

Edit: Rewrote method to provide examples of good code design...

```
var imageArray = [UIImage]()

func performLookupQuery() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "ParseClass")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?)
        if error == nil {
            let imageObjects = objects as! [PFObject]
            for object in imageObjects {
                let thumbnail = object["columnInParse"] as! PFFile
                thumbnail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?)
                    if error == nil {
                        if let image = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
                            imageArray.append(image)
                            //now your imageArray has all the images in it that you're trying to display
                            //you may need to reload the TableView after this to get it to display the images

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.image.image = nil
    cell.image.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

I didn't add all the error checking in the query method like you should, I was just writing it to show what you would do. Now that you have this query method, you can call it in `viewDidLoad` and then the results will be available when you try to load your table.

```
override func viewDidLoad(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad(animated)
    self.performLookupQuery()
}
```

Comment: And it won't even work properly because you can't async return the cell

Comment: Right, hence the reccomendation to move his query code outside of this method, return it into an array of `UIImage` and then use that to set the cell's image.

Comment: @Daniel I edited my answer to give you an overview (incomplete as it doesn't implement your other methods and the rest of the `tableView` `delegate` methods, but hopefully this helps you understand.

Comment: Should i pots all the code here for better view from code?

Comment: No what I've given you is sufficient to fix the most glaring issue you have. In numberOfRowsInSection make sure you return image array.count

Comment: Ok now its works but theres a little problem, the images is downloading but every time the table reload it fill in random order, how can i fix it?

Comment: You can try setting the `image` to nil before assigning it, but I also moved the call to `self.tableView.reloadData()` outside the inner block so it only gets called after everything has been returned.

Comment: Sorry but 'self.tableView.reloadData()' outside the inner block didn't show any images